# Dynamic, indexed array of structs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

How to create dynamic array of structs in c++ with keys that are not continous?

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Data {
   int name;
   int val;
}
```

I'm reading `names` from file of variable length.

Let's say it is:

```
1 2
3 5
7 12
```

In the end I'd like to have an (dynamic) array indexed by `name`,
like this (pseudo code):

```
arr[1] = *Data(1,2)
arr[3] = *Data(3,5)
arr[7] = *Data(7,12)
```

Expected result:

```
cout << arr[7]->val    // outputs 12
cout << arr[3]->val    // outputs 5

// array size = 3
```

How to write this in c++?
(assuming only basic feaures, no vectors, maps etc.)

So far I've tried something like this:

```
Data *distances = new Data[15];     // explicit size works
// Data *distances = new Data;       // this don't
distances[5] = myDataStruct;
```

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a `map` or `multimap`, although that is STL. Might still use it as a reference though

Comment: The saying with Modern C++ is "if you use pointers you are doing it wrong". Why not use STL's `map` or `unordered_map` ?

Comment: I guess the point is to learn how to create `map` without using predefined structures.

Comment: Well, pretty much the STL like `std::vector` and (closer to your goal) `std::map` are basic features, which is why they are in the `std` namespace.  But you can always look under the hood there if you want to get down to the nitty gritty

Comment: @takeshin that would be pointless - apart from wasted effort, getting a container correct takes a *lot* of work. For example, how do you *avoid* pointers? Copy or not? Allocations?

Comment: Problematic, the padding can be arbitrary. Most likely, all compilers will do this predictable, but I wouldn't count on that. Would be code smell anyway. If you really have to go with this without vectors, do it manually, that is arr[1] = Data.name et cetera. If I was given this task with the requirement of not using STL, I'd write classes that mimic STL.

Comment: @Sfisioza searching an ordered vector (eg by name) using binary search is *faster* than indexing.

Comment: "*assuming only basic feaures*" What is your definition of basic features? Your choice seems arbitrary.

Comment: Is this for a homework or for production code? In case of production code take Panagiotis' comment into account and use vector.

Comment: @WernerHenze Only for educational purposes (data structures). For production I'd use vectors and classes of course.

Comment: Then you should learn RB-trees and hash tables, because they are most powerful data structures for such work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This allocates memory for exactly one `Data` element.

```
Data *distances = new Data;
```

This allocates memory for 15 `Data` elements.

```
Data *distances = new Data[15];
```

To get what you want you could either

1. allocate a maximum number of elements and always stay in this boundary or
2. allocate a number of elements and for each new element resize the array (either C style malloc/realloc/free or C++ style new/delete, but then for resizing you need to and allocate a new array and copy the old values) or
3. provide a class that internally stores a list of all elements and exports an `operator[]` which does not do an array lookup but a find in the list

Comment: Looks like I need to start with array of size 1, then resize it to a bigger one in the reading loop if needed. I'm not familiar with `realloc` yet. Could you show me example? Is this possible without a loop rewriting all of the elements to a new array?

Comment: `man realloc` or Google `realloc` will help you. You cannot prevent rewriting to the new array. If the old memory block cannot be extended then a new memory block must be allocated. `realloc` does that internally for you, but for educational purpose of course you can do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Naïve implementation (this doesn't support adding new elements into the array, only lookup from an existing one. I'll leave a complete implementation as an exercise to the reader):

```
struct associative {
    Data* data_arr;
    Data* end;

    Data* operator[](int i) {
        return linear_search(data_arr, end, i);
    }
};
```

You could use `std::find` (with custom predicate) in place of `linear_search` but if that isn't included in *"basic features"* by your definition, then you'll just have to re-implement it. Linear search is not difficult to implement.

---

Few ways this naïve data structure can be improved:

- RAII ownership over the pointed memory would make the data structure much safer to use.
- Support for adding new elements into the internal array
- A better data-structure instead of an array: Binary search tree, or a hash map would allow asymptotically faster lookup.
- You are now re-implementing `std::map` or the unordered variant. Consider not reinventing the wheel.